# Python: how to form an array with comma?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, so please do not laugh at this question......

I have some arrays in a file, shown below

```
100 23 35 44 47 511
100 60 77 68 45 76
100 97 99 89 91 14
100 53 65
```

I have read the file and got every row with the following code,

```
f = file('new.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
results = []
for line in lines:
  print line
```

but in order to treat them as an input of a function, as below,

```
clf.fit ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

I think I need to format my arrays to make every array in the square brackets ([ ]) and add commas among them.
The final format I need is like this

```
clf.fit ([[100,23,35,44,47,511], [100,60,77,68,45,76], [100,97,99,89,91,14]], [100,53,65])
```

How can achieve it?

Comment: `results` isn't used in the above example. Where does `clf1` come from?

Comment: @Dan Sorry I did not write the whole code piece. clf = linear_model.LinearRegression(), which is a function of scikit-learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split each line into a list and create a list of lists (an array, essentially).

```
final_array = []

with open('new.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp_list = [int(x) for x in line.strip().split()]
        if len(temp_list) > 0:  # don't append an empty list (blank line)
            final_array.append(temp_list)

print final_array
```

You may want to do some additional sanity checking but this accomplishes the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you! The final array of this code is [['100', '23', '35', '44', '47', '\n'], ['100', '60', '77', '68', '77\n'], ['100', '97', '99', '89', '91', '\n'], ['100', '100', '43', '64', '64']]. How can I get rid of '\n'?

Comment: @KathyLee a list comprehension can do it in the same line of code, see update

Comment: @KathyLee see edit I just made, forgot to convert strings to integers and not have an int combined with newline char. Fixed in latest edit

Comment: Thank you. You save me again! I just tried the function but had "TypeError". But it works with your latest edit! :)

Comment: @KathyLee one last edit to make it a little more robust, you can add more checks as needed. If this solves your issue don't forget to mark as accepted. If not, let us know what is lacking.

Comment: Yes I have one more problem. If there is a space at the end a row, for example ['100', '23', '35', '44', '47', '\n'], the code can extract the row and get rid of '\n'; however, when there is no space at the end the row, which is like ['100', '23', '35', '44', '47\n''] ("\n" is not a singe index), how can I also get the correct row?

Comment: @KathyLee in other words, your data has more than one row on the same line in some cases? That is a data cleanup issue. You will need parameters for how to know when a row should be delimited (i.e. always 5 integers per row or something like this?). However that was not part of your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) to load your file as an array.Or if you don't want to use `numpy` you better to use `csv` module to load your data and them convert them to integer.

```
import csv 

with open('new.txt') as f:
   spam_reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
   my_array = [map(int,row) for row in spam_reader]
```

Note that if you are not sure about the validation of your data the preceding code will raise a `ValueError`, which in that case you need to handle the exception using a `try-except` expression.

```
my_array = []
for row in spam_reader:
   try:
       my_array.append(map(int,row))
   except ValueError:
       # do stuff
```